# How do I make g++ permanently compile using the C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I'm using g++ 4.8.1, and unless I explicitly state `-std=c++11` then it always compiles C++ code using the '98 standard. How do I permanently set the flag?

EDIT: Also, I'm using Windows. And command prompt.

Comment: _Permanently_ save the compiler options in a makefile.

Answer (score 2):

g++ is configured via a **spec** file.

you can google that, and edit it.

alternatives to configuring the basic compiler via its spec file include

- batch file to invoke it
- console alias to invoke it (use `doskey` command)
- just use the Nuwen distribution, which is *already* configured for C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following line in a batch file, and call that instead, passing the arguments you'd normally pass to g++ to the batch file.

```
g++ -std=c++11 %*
```

[This](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) is the only reference I could find for `%*`

> The %* modifier is a unique modifier that represents all arguments passed in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias for whichever shell you use. Usually, the alias must be stored in a start-up script for it to become permanent.

For bash:

```
alias g++='g++ -std=c++11'
```

For Window's cmd.exe:

```
doskey g++=g++ -std=c++11 $*
```

While you're at it, `-Wall` and `-pedantic` are also useful to set by default. Look them up!